# Why the extra 'se' in 'se espera se que supere'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbo-pronominal

From a New York Times (Spanish version) [article](https://www.nytimes.com/es/2018/07/30/madrid-venezolanos-inversiones-inmobiliarias/):

> MADRID — . La inflación es vertiginosa y **se espera se que supere** un millón por ciento para finales de año.

I know what the sentence means, but why the extra 'se' after 'espera'?

Is this a translation error (typo)?  Would a native speaker from Spain say it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong. It's probably meant to be

> Se espera **que se** supere 1M.